# Angular Replace all semi-colon once in string

Tags: angular, typescript

im working in angular project typescript , and i want to replace all ',' with one '.' , my issue is tha the replace method replace them with '.' , here is an exemple :
'1,2' should be '1.2' and also '1,,2' should be '1.2' this is my code :

```
let data1 ='1,2';
let data2 ='1,,2';
let data3 ='1,,,2';
console.log(data1.replace(',' , '.'); // print 1.2
console.log(data2.replace(',' , '.'); // print 1..2 so i want to force it 1.2
console.log(data3.replace(',' , '.'); // print 1...2 so i want to force it 1.2
```

do you have any suggestion to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp like this one:

```
data.replace(/[,]+/gm, '.')
```

Comment: thanks for yor response , it works as console.log but when i uset it like this  modifyValueOnChange(data: any) {
    data = data.replace(/[,]+/gm, '.');
    this.form.controls.amount.setValue(data);
} it dosen't work